# Render clipping of near polygon objects in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm modelling 3D objects in Processing and have an issue whereby when objects get too close to the camera their renders are clipped (i.e. the closest bits of the object to the camera are not rendered).  This happens both in P3D and OPENGL modes.  The right-hand image below illustrate:

[image][image]

Any idea how to stop this happening? Code is below, and is testable online at [openprocessing.org](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/98898). Many thanks in advance.

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 400, P3D);
  stroke(0);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  fill(200);

  // initialise camera variables
  scaleY = PI/height;
  scaleX = 2*PI/width;
  camDir = PI/3;
  camElev = PI/2;
  MouseX = width/2;
  MouseY = height/3;
  turnCamera();
  camF_rel = setVector(camDir, camElev);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  // CAMERA & CONTROL OPERATIONS
  MouseX = constrain(mouseX, 0, width);
  MouseY = constrain(mouseY, 0, height);
  setCamera();
  camera(camP.x, camP.y, camP.z, camF_abs.x, camF_abs.y, camF_abs.z, 0, 0, -1);

  // DRAW ENVIRONMENT
  // checkered plane
  fill(150,200,255);
  for (int i=-10; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=-10; j<10; j++) {
      noStroke();
      if ((i+j)%2 == 0) rect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
    }
  }
  // vertical line
  noFill();
  stroke(100);
  box(1000);
}


// camera position and focus variables
PVector camP = new PVector(0, 1200, 700); // camera position
PVector camF_abs = new PVector();     // camera focus (absolute position)
PVector camF_rel = new PVector();     // camera focus (relative vector)
float camDir, camElev;                // last camera bearing/elevation angles
float mx, my;                         // last mouse X/Y
float MouseX, MouseY;                 // replicate inbuilt mouse variables
float scaleY;                         // scale mouseY inputs to vertical movement
float scaleX;                         // scale mouseX inputs to horizontal movement
int direction = 0;                    // code for controling movement
float moveSpeed = 10;                 // overall controls responsiveness


// main camera calculation operations
void setCamera() {
  camF_rel = setVector(camDir, camElev);
  if (direction >= 1 & direction <= 4) moveCamera(moveSpeed);
  if (direction >= 5 & direction <= 6) elevCamera(moveSpeed);

  camF_abs = camF_rel.get();
  camF_abs.add(camP);
}


PVector setVector(float dir, float elev){
  //generic function to calculate the PVector based on radial coordinates
  PVector v = new PVector(cos(dir), sin(dir), 0);
  float fz = -sin(elev);
  float fy = sqrt(1-pow(fz, 2));
  v.mult(fy);
  v.z = fz;
  return(v);
}


void moveCamera (float speed) {
  PVector moveto = new PVector();

  // left / right movement
  if (direction%2 == 0) {
    float dir = 0;
    if (direction == 2) dir = camDir + PI/2;  // right
    else                dir = camDir - PI/2;  // left
    PVector v = setVector(dir, 0);
    v.mult(speed);
    camP.add(v);
  }

  // forward / backward movement
  else {
    moveto = camF_rel.get();
    if (direction == 1) moveto.mult(-1); // forward
  }

  moveto.normalize();
  moveto.mult(speed);
  camP.sub(moveto);
}


void turnCamera(){
  float x = MouseX - mx;
  float x_scaled = x * scaleX;
  float y = MouseY - my;
  float y_scaled = y * scaleY;
  camDir += x_scaled;
  camElev += y_scaled;
  mx = MouseX;
  my = MouseY;

}


void elevCamera (float speed) {
  if (direction == 5) {  // lower camera
    camP.z -= speed;               
    camF_abs.z -= speed;
  }
  else {                 // raise camera
    camP.z += speed;               
    camF_abs.z += speed;
  }
}


void keyPressed() {
  if      (keyCode == 38 | key == 'w') direction = 1;  // move forward
  else if (keyCode == 39 | key == 'd') direction = 2;  // move right
  else if (keyCode == 40 | key == 's') direction = 3;  // move backward
  else if (keyCode == 37 | key == 'a') direction = 4;  // move left
  else if (key == 'z')                 direction = 5;  // lower camera
  else if (key == 'x')                 direction = 6;  // raise camera
}


void keyReleased() {
  direction = 0;
}


void mouseMoved() {  // turns the camera
  turnCamera();
}
```

Comment: https://forum.processing.org/topic/3d-clipping-problem-i-think might help. Not sure if you've already done so but putting your question on the Processing forum will get your some sort of help a lot quicker than SO. Processing doesn't seem to be very popular around here.

Comment: Thanks @nickecarlo, that page escaped my earlier search.

Answer (score 4):

You can control the near and far clipping distances by calling the [perspective()](https://processing.org/reference/perspective_.html) function in Processing.

Add these lines to your setup() and the issue is gone:

```
float fov = PI/3.0;
float cameraZ = (height/2.0) / tan(fov/2.0);
float nearClippingDistance = 0.01; // default is cameraZ/10.0
perspective(fov, float(width)/float(height), nearClippingDistance, cameraZ*10.0);
```

You can find out the default near clipping distance in your sketch by adding this line after the previous ones:

```
println(cameraZ/10.0); // output: 34.6410
```